# NetFramework convert to Net Core (HttpWebRequest)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a library for 4.5 net fw. I need do the same but for net core.

Big beer for person which can repair this..

[Code from VS with errors (screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL9cr.png)
MY code:

```
string returnData = String.Empty;

            var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
                webRequest.UserAgent = ".NET";
                webRequest.Method = method;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webRequest.Host = "coinbase.com";

                string nonce = Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.Now.Ticks).ToString();
                string message = nonce + url;
                string signature = HashEncode(HashHMAC(StringEncode(API_SECRET), StringEncode(message)));

                var whc = new WebHeaderCollection();
                whc.Add("ACCESS_KEY: " + API_KEY);
                whc.Add("ACCESS_SIGNATURE: " + signature);
                whc.Add("ACCESS_NONCE: " + nonce);
                webRequest.Headers = whc;

                using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        returnData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my code as below. Hope to help, my friend:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
                webRequest.UserAgent = ".NET";
                webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webRequest.Host = "coinbase.com";

                var whc = new WebHeaderCollection
                {
                    "ACCESS_KEY: " + API_KEY,
                    "ACCESS_SIGNATURE: " + signature,
                    "ACCESS_NONCE: " + nonce
                };
                webRequest.Headers = whc;

                using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        returnData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Camilson: Sorry, my friend. I used .Net Framework 4.6. And I have checked, really no error.

Comment: Ok but this must be NET CORE. I need run this code on linux

Comment: I replace GetResponse to GetResponseAsync - 1 less error but still is  webrequest - https://gyazo.com/3767330e7afd375c7b40ba10c67f168e

Comment: @Camilson: It's Ok. I will test and edit my answer right now. Sorry, my friend.

Comment: @Camilson: You can refer this link to find the answer: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/6903087e-5e5c-445a-be20-cee0a7eb434e.aspx

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a new Headers collection and overwrite the existing one? You already put something there and you are then throwing it away...